# RStudio server manipulate and rstudio packages

Tags: linux, r, rstudio-server

I have an RStudio server (0.99.441) instance shared by several users, running on an Ubuntu 12.04 server with R 3.2.0.

One user complained that the statement `library(manipulate)` was crashing because the package was missing. Looking into the issue, I found that some users had the `manipulate` package installed in their home under `/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/manipulate` when others didn't. No trace of it in the system libraries. The users who do have it didn't install or copy it manually, so it was installed there automatically.

From what I have found, the `manipulate` package comes with the `rstudio` package, and with RStudio desktop they are installed automatically at session startup if not found. However this does not happen when starting a new session on RStudio server, and I couldn't find documentation on this issue.

One solution could be to simply copy these folders to the other users' homes, or even to the system library (`rstudio` package comes with RStudio and is not on CRAN), but I would like to understand how these packages ended up there in the first place and to find a clean way to install them.